# How can I hide a recurring Calendar event?

Tags: calendar, exchange

In order to reserve a conference room in my office (via Exchange) I have to send a meeting request to the room's calendar. I have a recurring daily event to book a room indefinitely, and I don't want this recurring event showing up in my calendar because it's just clutter.

At the very least, I've turned off notifications. Is there any way to hide the event so it's not constantly visible in Calendar?

Comment: Outlook Calendar ?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to create a new calendar within the Calendar app, label it what you'd like (perhaps "Hidden"?) and move any events you'd like to hide over to this calendar. When done, just uncheck the box next to the calendar and it disappears.